# BufferedReader not receiving message over socket

Tags: java, sockets, io

The situation is that there are 4 'Helper' threads, each with a connection to all helpers (including itself). I am indeed autoflushing. Below, this.id is an int used to identify the helper running the code. In debugging, I've watched helper 0 send a message to itself (by sending over all connections), but when it should receive the message (over connection 0), it acts like its BufferedReader has an empty buffer.

SOLVED: Woops I had a design flaw. I made sure each helper kept only one socket per helper that it needs to communicate with, but this is incorrect when a helper connects to itself. In this case, keeping only one socket means the other endpoint of communication (with itself) is lost.

My program spins forever in here (must be empty buffer):

```
        boolean clientStreamReady = false;
        boolean helperStreamReady = false;
        while (!(clientStreamReady || helperStreamReady)) {
            clientStreamReady = this.inFromClient.ready();
            helperStreamReady = this.helperIns.get(this.id).ready();

            if (clientStreamReady) {
                message = this.inFromClient.readLine();
            }
            else if (helperStreamReady){
                message = this.helperIns.get(this.id).readLine();
            }
        }
```

The message is "broadcast" here:

```
    for (PrintWriter out : this.helperOuts) {
        out.println(this.id + "," + kind + "," + this.clock.getTime());
    }
```

The IO from the sockets, set up prior to the above, is done here:

```
    for (Socket socket : this.helperSockets) {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            this.helperOuts.add(out);
            this.helperIns.add(in);
    }
```

If the socket setup code is needed tell me and I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

Do your PrintWriters have automatic flushing enabled? If not, a simple out.flush() at the end of your broadcast loop might already do the trick.

Comment: Yes I do. Good suggestion though, not setting auto flush got me a couple times before.